# RoR Render Partial Tabindex

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some code

`= link_to "Log In", ""
= render :partial => "user/session/new"`

I am trying to trigger this not only when Log In is clicked , but when you hit tab on the keyboard ... how do I do this in RoR

Thanks for your help

Comment: What exactly are you trying to trigger? The rendering of the partial?

Comment: You'll have to use some custom js event handler to detect the tab event.

Comment: I ended up using javascript to solve my problem, dint have to change anything in RoR

Answer (score 0):

You can use `link_to` tag available in Rails for doing the accepted thing that you want on link to you can give the path of the controller.

e.g.:

```
 <%= link_to "Sign-In", new_user_session_path, :class => "dropdown-toggle", :data => {:toggle=>"dropdown"} %>
```

which is similar to

```
 <a href="users/sessions/new" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign-In</a>
```